# Ionic 2 populate dynamic options with one selected via ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've searched the highways of the interwebs and have not come up with a viable solution to my problem.

I have this code that creates a dynamic list of options from an api and this works greatly.

```
        <ion-select
          formControlName="dataset"
          (ionChange)="checkDataset($event)"
          [(ngModel)]="chosenDataObj.dataset">
          <ion-option
            *ngFor="let data of dataSet">
            {{data}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
```

This application saves the "dataset" information to NativeStorage and upon returning to this page, retrieves it respectively. I need to set the value of the dynamic ion-option's to the previously selected value. I have tried

```
ngModel=chosenDataObj.dataset
[selected]="chosenDataObj.dataset"
[checked]="foo"
```

and a wide array of variations of each of those but to no avail. According to many other sources, the ngModel is the correct way to go, but as it is coupled with the FormBuilder, it seems to clash and not set it correctly.

If it is any help, I load in the chosenDataObj.dataset via a promise in the TS code and I know the value is there because I can use it as a placeholder attribute and it works as expected.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks community!

Comment: did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before.

This is what worked for me -

Set the value directly in `formGroup`:

```
this.form_name.controls['dataset'].setValue(chosenDataObj.dataset)
```

depending on when you want to show for example when formBuilder is loaded, ionChange event or save.

Comment: Thanks for your time @suraj but unfortunately, I have tried this before and it doesnt work either. I have logged the form itself and the "value" is even showing the correct value but its not visible on the front end. Ran an updateValueAndValidity and still no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks mate

Comment: maybe try ngZone .. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html